# AngularJS - Authentication with Bearer Token and Web API 2.0

Tags: angularjs, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have the problem that even though I set the `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization` to `null` I am still capable of accessing the `[Authorize]` part of my Web API 2.0 application.

This problem doesn't arise when I start the application from scratch and try to retrieve the data via an initial GET request. This is when I get an error from the `$http` callback function.

Any guesses why this is happening? I am quite confident that the bearer token is stored somewhere in the browser and doesn't get deleted properly ...

Chrome (With bearer token):

[image]

Chrome (Without bearer token):

[image]

Internet Explorer (no bearer Token attribute):

[image]

First of all, the authentication property in IE is completely missing. Second, in Chrome everything works perfectly. In IE I have the issue that I can't erase the token for the logout request. The login part with the summary of the regions `[Authorize]` part works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't also configured jQuery to do this, via something like `$.ajaxSetup`

Comment: I rarely use JQuery when I work with Angular. Is there a way to debug this issue? The property is set to null, thats all I can see.

Comment: I'd start by confirming that you actually are sending the header; chrome debugging tools will let you inspect all the request you send, for example. It's kinda hard to "accidentally" specify an authorization header...

Comment: I've added some further printscreens to my initial answer - appartently the property is completely absent in IE but not so in Google Chrome ...

Comment: I'm not even sure what your problem is. You don't want the Authorization header to be set, right? Under what circumstances does it show up right now?

Comment: It still shows up in IE, even though I set it to null (logout). In Google chrome everything works fine.

Comment: Your screenshot shows it's not there in IE, though...?

Comment: For some reason the login process still works in IE. When I am logged in and supposed to send the bearer token for the `[Authorize]` part, it looks like the last print screen. The property doesn't appear in the header but for some reason I still get access to the data. The only problem is the logout process, which doesn't seem to work. Why the property doesn't show up makes me also curious ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the request that have been set, if any Authentification header is there. Also try to verify that you are using the `[Authorize]` attribute from `System.Web.Http` and not `System.Web.Mvc`