# AngularJS get request always send undefined Bearer token

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

**My get request with authorization header :**

```
 return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/values', {
    headers: {
                 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authService.authentication.token
             }
    }).then(function(results) {
            return results;
    });
```

**The request header it sends :**
[image]
Even-if i put the hard-coded token (`'Authorization': 'Bearer my-hard-coded-token'`), then also it doesn't change.

I see some similar question like [AngularJS - Authentication with Bearer Token and Web API 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26549279/3835843) , but it doesn't solve my issue. Can anybody tell me why it sent's always `undefined`.

Comment: undefined means there isn't any value in authService.authentication.token. Can you do a console.log and see ?

Comment: try another variant: `$http({method: 'GET',url:serviceBase + 'api/values',headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authService.authentication.token}})`